# Subtitles in the menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I bought a premium template and imported the sample settings and the menus have subtitles like this: "Home" + "Start here" below it.

I can't find where to set or change these subtitles. Where could it possibly be? If there's no option for it, where do I look in the code?

The template is ["Robust"](http://themeforest.net/item/robust-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/4176764?WT.ac=portfolio_thumb&WT.seg_1=portfolio_thumb&WT.z_author=rifki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **Appearance > Menu** in the Dashboard.

Look under description.

If you don't see it, click on **Screen Options** on top right corner and select description.

Comment: I tried this, there's no acces to those subtitles and the menu created by them looks exactly the same as those created by me, except mine are missing the subtitles

Comment: I found this image, try finding that: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-91NQlW1hlUU/UTz2QfbJakI/AAAAAAAAAHQ/m2dMmNx9ZhQ/s480/FireShot%20Pro%20Screen%20Capture%20%23230%20-%20%27Menus%20%E2%80%B9%20Robust%20%E2%80%94%20WordPress%27%20-%20www_freshthemes_net_demo_robust_wp-admin_nav-menus_php.png

Comment: that option is missing for me! that's exactly what I'm looking for **Edit: I found it under Appearance-Menu-Screen options:check description box. Thanks!**